# Retrieve one value from default dict on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis

I have a dict which I populate with data using *setdefault* method as follows:

```
if date not in call_dict:
    call_dict.setdefault(date, [0, 0]).append(0)
else:
    call_dict[date][0] += 1
    if x[12] != 'ANSWERED':
        call_dict[date][1] += 1
    call_dict[date][2] = 100*(call_dict[date][1]/call_dict[date][0])
```

At the end of this process I have a dict which is structured like this:

> {'key' : value0, value1, value2}

Then I have to plot only *key* and *value2* (as *value2* is a function of the *key*) but I can't find the way to access this value. 
I tried *myDict.values()* but it did not work (as expected). I would really like to avoid creating another list/dict/anything because of script performance and  also to achieve 
that I would still have to reach for the *value2* which would solve my problem.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Sample values of dict:

```
{'08:23': [45, 17, 37.77777777777778], 
'08:24': [44, 15, 34.090909090909086], 
'08:25': [46, 24, 52.17391304347826], 
'08:48': [49, 19, 38.775510204081634],
```

Comment: Please provide sample dict data

Comment: so you want to plot the pairs (key_i , value2_i ) ?

Comment: @Mr.J please check edited post

Comment: @GerardoFlores if by _i you mean: first, second, etc then yes :)

Comment: there's an issue with the sample values you provided. A dictionary print usualy looks like {'key0': [45, 17, 37], 'key1' : [44, 15, 34],..} So what you want to plot is (key0, 37), (key1, 34)?

Comment: @GerardoFlores my bad, I posted only values of the dict. Please find fixed data in post.

Comment: while I was busy figuring out what you wanted, somebody provided the answer I was thinking about sharing with you. It can easily be done with list comprehension, so you should look at Patrick's answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get them from the dictionary with a list comprehension:

```
data = { "2018-07-01": [45, 17, 37.77777777777778], 
         "2018-07-02": [44, 15, 34.090909090909086], 
         "2018-07-03": [46, 24, 52.17391304347826], 
         "2018-07-04": [49, 19, 38.775510204081634]}


xy = [(x,data[x][2]) for x in data.keys()] # extract tuples of (date-key, 3rd value)

print(xy)
```

Output:

```
[('2018-07-01', 37.77777777777778), ('2018-07-02', 34.090909090909086), 
 ('2018-07-03', 52.17391304347826), ('2018-07-04', 38.775510204081634)]
```

If you need them for plotting you might want to do:

```
x,y = zip(*xy)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
('2018-07-01', '2018-07-02', '2018-07-03', '2018-07-04')  # x
(37.77777777777778, 34.090909090909086, 52.17391304347826, 38.775510204081634)  # y
```

and supply those to your plotting library as `x` and `y` data.

Doku: [zip(*iterables)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)